# How to get an ObservableCollection list item which inside another ObservableCollection list?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, sorting, collectionview

I have a class ***PlayerVM.cs***, that has a property:

```
public ObservableCollection<PlaylistVM> PlayLists
        {
            get { return _playLists; }
            set { _playLists = value; }
        }
```

***PlaylistVM.cs*** also has its own collection:

```
public ObservableCollection<CompositionVM> Songs
        {
            get
            {
                return _songs;
            }
            set
            {
                _songs = value;
            }
        }
```

By that, my PlayerVM has a list of playlists, and each that playlist has its own list of songs.
I need to display list of songs being sorted alphabetically. But I don't want to change their order in ObservableCollections, I want change their order only in GUI (only display them alphabetically, not to change real order).
I am new in wpf (and xaml), and today I've learned only how to display PLAYLISTS  NAMES ordered alphabetically. I am doing it by code:

```
<Window x:Class="Player_beta.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Player_beta">
    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding PlayLists}"  x:Key="plView"><!--here I would like to get access to PlayLists.Songs-->
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="plNAME"/> <!--and here I would like to get NAME(that property of 'Songs' which contains songtitle) instead of plNAME - name of playlist)-->
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
 </Window.Resources>
<!-- etc...-->
            <TreeView Name="treeCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource plView}}" >
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Songs}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding plNAME}"/> <!-- <-- here is where the name of PLAYLIST shows-->
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NAME}"/> <!-- <-- here is where the name of song shows-->
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, you can add a `CollectionView` property to the `PlaylistVM` class:

```
public CollectionView songsCollectionView;
public CollectionView SongsCollectionView
{
    get 
    {
        if (songsCollectionView == null)
        {
            songsCollectionView  = new CollectionView(Songs);
            songsCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("plNAME", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }

        return songsCollectionView;
    }
}
```

and then you can bind your xaml like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SongsCollectionView}">
```

This should fulfill your requirement of showing sorted songs in GUI without changing the original collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the **`ICollectionView`** instance in PlaylistVM.cs class and bind with it. This way original list will remain unaffected as well.

```
private ICollectionView songsView;
public ICollectionView SongsView
{
    get
    {
        if (songsView== null)
        {
            songsView= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Songs);
            songsView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name",
                                               ListSortDirection.Ascending));
        }
        return songsView;
    }
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SongsView}">
```

Comment: Wow. It's almost like we copied each other. :)

Comment: Yogesh, yes. And I dont know what answer to accept)
But, @Yogesh and Rohit Vats, thanks, it works)

Comment: Haha. You can flip a coin and select. ;) He typed faster than me by some seconds though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient, but will get the job done. Note that it does NOT detect if the name of any of the songs has changed. It also will rebuild the entire list in the UI everytime a song is added or removed.

```
public class PlaylistVM: System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<CompositionVM> _songs;
    public ObservableCollection<CompositionVM> Songs
    {
        get
        {
            return _songs;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_songs != value)
            {
                //if old value not null, unhook event
                if (_songs != null)
                {
                    _songs.CollectionChanged -= FireSongsChanged;
                }
                //change the value
                _songs = value;

                //if new value !=null, then attach handlers.
                if (_songs != null)
                {
                    _songs.CollectionChanged += FireSongsChanged;
                }

                //this will fire the 
                FireSongsChanged(null, null);
            }

        }
    }

    void FireSongsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //the collection of songs has changed, tell UI that it needs to requery the list of ordered songs.
        var ev = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (ev != null)
        {
            ev(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs("OrderedSongs"));
        }
    }

    //set the UI to bind to the following list of the songs. ordered by name.
    public IEnumerable<CompositionVM> OrderedSongs
    {
        get
        {
            return Songs.OrderBy(song => song.Name);
        }
    }


}
```